# How do I softcode a workflow activity in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation, business-logic, workflow-activity

I need to write a static method which is performing some kind of parsing on a string
with signature like:

```
string ParseMessage(string messageToParse)
```

I would like the whole method ParseMessage to be soft-coded, i.e. not precompiled within the main output of the project, which is a common windows forms application.
How do I do this using a workflow activity?

I would like to:

1. Create an activity defined in a xaml file
2. Load the activity into my windows forms application
3. Run the activity by passing the arguments (a variable of string type)
4. Get the result in a variable of string type

Comment: By saying "not precompiled within the main output of the project" do you mean to have the static method in a dll instead? And why Workflow? It sounds like you just need an event handler. Maybe we're missing a big piece of your story.

Comment: Maybe I was not so clear as I expected. I need to have an entire piece of business logic computed inside the method ParseMessage. Then, I need to customize ParseMessage when the program is already deployed on different machines. I would avoid dll since I need a higher extent of flebility (i.e. open the xaml and modify directly the business logic, at runtime)

Comment: Can you provide examples of this business logic? That is two cases of this logic so we get an idea of the kinds of things that could be different and how you express them.

Comment: Typical example could be a workflow parsing a string from another string. In this case I will have to search for some kinds of constant string inside the string passed as argument. This can be different in respect of the format of the string, separators, etc. Then I have to manipulate the results of this first extraction through some sort of rules-based algorithm. At the end I get my string parsed into the message format I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very interesting tutorial from Channel9, going directly to the point:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/VS2010/WCFWF/IntroToWF/Exercise-5-Testing-Workflows